# assigning the value of function to a variable of same name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading about hoisting, and in my editor I was trying this

function loginUser() {
return "Hi"}

const loginUser = loginUser();

I am getting the error cannot access "loginUser" before reinitialisation. Has it got something to do with hoisting. could I get the explanation as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: Without knowing where in your code you are experiencing that error, I'm guessing it might have something to do with the missing semi-colon after "Hi".

Comment: Why would you try something like that? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Russ — It has nothing to do with ASI.

Comment: It would work if you used `var` instead of `const`. But it's dangerous (which is why I always recommend using `const` when possible, to catch potential bugs like this).

Comment: Both firefox and chrome throw with this code, but because of the redeclaration.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error you are getting. My JS engines log:

> SyntaxError: Identifier 'loginUser' has already been declared

Your function declaration declares a variable named `loginUser`.

Your `const` declaration declares a variable name `loginUser`.

`const` can't redeclare a variable that already exists in the same scope, hence the error.

---

Your error message, which seems to be an oddity of your environment, is saying that since you have just said `const loginUser` you can't read the value `loginUser` to assign to it because the new one doesn't exist yet.